# Changing my Projects Installation Path in Visual Studio (Express 2013)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation-path

Could someone please direct me to the specific place in the Project Properties menu (Visual Studio Express) where I can change the installation path for my application...?

Comment: What do you mean by `Installation Path`? Do you mean the path that `exe` file will be located?

Comment: I create a Windows forms type application within my VS project. I then build the install set but the install set builder uses its own designated path when I come to install the application on another PC. I want to change this to a path of my choosing...

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

1. Open project property window
2. Go to `Publish->Installation Folder URL`, add your path to it

Comment: Its asking for a UNC path name...? (I want to install to C:\BESTBETSoftware)
I have tried : 

\\localhost\c$\BESTBETSoftware

Doesnt make any difference...

Comment: I checked the whole property page, didn't find somewhere to set install location. It may not be supported. You may use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) instead.